# AttributeError : 'dict' object has no attribute 'forward'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
# my program
import turtle
t=turtle.pen()
for x in range(100):
    t.forward(x)
t.left(90)
```

When i run this program come error as below

```
AttributeError : 'dict' object has no attribute 'forward'
```

Comment: You could start by reading the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pen)

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: What were you expecting `turtle.pen()` to be?

Comment: You called `pen`, and then tried to move the return value with a turtle command.  How did you imagine this would be valid?  We expect you to refer to the documentation and to tutorials and examples before you post here.  Even then, we expect you to check the types and values of your variables before posting.

Answer (score 2):

```
import turtle 
print(turtle.pen())
```

If you run this you will observe that pen() returns a dictionary and forward() is not a valid dictionary attribute. You can simply write :

```
turtle.forward(x)
```